# knockout mapping plugin, create observable for head node also

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Does anyone know how to set the mapping options to make the head node an observable?

For example if I have a structure like:

```
var myModel = {
table: [{...},{...},{...}]
configOptions: { someoptions... }
otherstuff: thisbecomesanobservable
}
```

and I call

```
var data = ko.mapping.fromJS(myModel)
```

For some reason `data` is not an observable, only the leaves are.
This means when I later call

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(ajaxResponse, {}, data);
```

and I need to have subscriptions and dependencies on data, I can't because it not observable.

I'm doing this now to wrap it manually:

```
if (typeof vm.Table === 'undefined') {
    vm.Table = ko.observable();
    vm.Table(ko.mapping.fromJS(response.Model));
}
else {
    var temp = vm.Table();
    ko.mapping.fromJS(response.Model, {}, temp);
    vm.Table(temp); 
}
```

but this is extremely painful to have to put all this after each ajax call

Any tips? Ideas? Thoughts? How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reconstruct what you are doing (I took the liberty of renaming your `data` variable to `vm`, as this is indeed your viewmodel):

**Markup:**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: table">
    <li data-bind="text: someProperty"></li>
</ul>

<label>Hax option value:</label>
<label data-bind="text: configOptions.hax"></label>

<input type="button" data-bind="click: doAjaxCall" value="Get new stuff" />
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
    var initialModel = {
        table: [{ someProperty: 1 }, { someProperty: 2 }],
        configOptions: { hax: '2tm' },
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(initialModel);

        //Attach a function to viewmodel before binding
        vm.doAjaxCall = function(dataVal, event)
        {
            //A Json object, we pretend, this came back from an AJAX call.
            //Obviously, it should have same layout as initial object, base for the viewmodel.
            var newData = {
                table: [{ someProperty: 3 }, { someProperty: 4 }, { someProperty: 5 }],
                configOptions: { hax: '4tm' },
            };

            //Update viewmodel with the new data
            ko.mapping.fromJS(newData, vm);
        };

        //Init knockout
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    });
</script>
```

Click the button, and you should see the vm get updated, bubbling out and updating the databound objects as well.

Was it something like this? If you have similar code, but not working, please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or the like.

---

Comment: No I need vm.data not to update the whole viewmodel, just part of it. Putting together a fiddle now.

Comment: please see that fiddle. I need ComplexViewModel1 and ComplexViewModel2 to stay observables. because I have custom bindings that need to do things when they are updated, etc. For simplicity I did not put all that in my example, just giving you an idea of what I am trying to do

Comment: It's really hard to understand, what you are trying to do. You write "I need vm.data not to update the whole viewmodel" - what vm.data? There's no 'data' property on your vm. "I need ComplexViewModel1 and ComplexViewModel2 to stay observables" - they will. What do you mean?

I will try to help you the best I can, but please come up with a fiddle with an example of something, that works - something you can actually run in your browser, and stuff happens - and explain, what the problem is.

Comment: I appreciate the help, i figured it out.

Comment: Thanks for  trying to help, it led me down the right path, sorry I was not more clear, I was trying to use the mapping options to result in what I did above, it was hard to explain. All I wanted to do was to use mapping.fromJS to get data from the server and put it into an observable. but not for the whole viewmodel like all the examples show.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone, when you get data back from the server and its a complex object, this is how to wrap it in an observable:

```
vm.updateModel = function (observable, data) {
    if (observable() == undefined)
        observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
    else {
        var temp = observable();
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, temp);
        observable(temp);
    }
};
```

It was quite shocking that the mapping plugin can't do this either by default or with mappingOptions...